# How to get build time env Vars into docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am struggling to get build time env vars into my docker container. I am running a docker compose file:

````
version: "3.8"

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.testing
      target: api_serve
    ports:
      - "8911:8911"
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file: .env

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.testing
      target: web_serve
    ports:
      - "8910:8910"
    depends_on:
      - api
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - API_PROXY_TARGET=http://api:8911
      - API_HOST=http://api:8911

  db:
    image: postgis/postgis:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgrespw
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./postgrestesting:/var/lib/postgresql/data


  # After starting with `docker compose -f ./docker-compose.prod.yml up`,
  # use the console to run commands in the container:
  #
  # ```
  # docker compose -f ./docker-compose.prod.yml run --rm -it console /bin/bash
  # ```
  console:
    user: root
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.testing
      target: console
    tmpfs:
      - /tmp
    command: "true"
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - db
````

the dockerfile looks like this:

````
# base
# ----
FROM node:20-bookworm-slim as base

RUN corepack enable

# We tried to make the Dockerfile as lean as possible. In some cases, that means we excluded a dependency your project needs.
# By far the most common is Python. If you're running into build errors because `python3` isn't available,
# uncomment the line below here and in other stages as necessary:
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    openssl \
    # python3 make gcc \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
#

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY .yarn/releases .yarn/releases
COPY .yarn/patches .yarn/patches
COPY .yarnrc.yml .
COPY package.json .
COPY packages packages

COPY api/package.json api/
COPY web/package.json web/
COPY yarn.lock .

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/.yarn/berry/index
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/.cache

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/home/node/.yarn/berry/cache,uid=1000 \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/home/node/.cache,uid=1000 \
    CI=1 yarn install

COPY redwood.toml .
COPY graphql.config.js .
COPY .env.defaults .env.defaults

# api build
# ---------
FROM base as api_build

# If your api side build relies on build-time environment variables,
# specify them here as ARGs. (But don't put secrets in your Dockerfile!)
#
# ARG MY_BUILD_TIME_ENV_VAR

COPY api api
COPY scripts scripts
COPY packages packages
RUN yarn rw build api

# web prerender build
# -------------------
FROM api_build as web_build_with_prerender

COPY web web
COPY packages packages
RUN yarn rw build web

# web build
# ---------
FROM base as web_build

COPY web web
COPY api api
COPY packages packages

ARG NODE_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ARG MAP_GEOAPIFY_KEY
ENV MAP_GEOAPIFY_KEY=supersecret
ARG MAP_MAPTILER_KEY
ENV MAP_MAPTILER_KEY=supersecret
ARG PUBLIC_URL
ENV PUBLIC_URL=''

ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=32768
RUN yarn rw build web --no-prerender

# api serve
# ---------
FROM node:20-bookworm-slim as api_serve

RUN apt install bash

RUN corepack enable

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    openssl \
    # python3 make gcc \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY .yarn .yarn
COPY packages packages
COPY .yarnrc.yml .
COPY package.json .
COPY api/package.json api/
COPY yarn.lock .

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/.yarn/berry/index
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/.cache

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/home/node/.yarn/berry/cache,uid=1000 \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/home/node/.cache,uid=1000 \
    CI=1 yarn workspaces focus api --production

COPY redwood.toml .
COPY graphql.config.js .
COPY .env.defaults .env.defaults
COPY serve-api.sh .

COPY --from=api_build /home/node/app/api/dist /home/node/app/api/dist
COPY --from=api_build /home/node/app/api/db /home/node/app/api/db
COPY --from=api_build /home/node/app/node_modules/.prisma /home/node/app/node_modules/.prisma

ENV NODE_ENV=production

CMD [ "node_modules/.bin/rw-server", "api"]


# web serve
# ---------
FROM node:20-bookworm-slim as web_serve

RUN corepack enable

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY .yarn .yarn
COPY packages packages
COPY .yarnrc.yml .
COPY package.json .
COPY web/package.json web/
COPY yarn.lock .

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/.yarn/berry/index
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/.cache

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/home/node/.yarn/berry/cache,uid=1000 \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/home/node/.cache,uid=1000 \
    CI=1 yarn workspaces focus web --production

COPY redwood.toml .
COPY graphql.config.js .
COPY .env.defaults .env.defaults

COPY --from=web_build /home/node/app/web/dist /home/node/app/web/dist

ENV NODE_ENV=production \
    # API_PROXY_TARGET=http://api:8911
    API_HOST=http://api:8911

# We use the shell form here for variable expansion.
CMD "node_modules/.bin/rw-web-server" "--apiHost" "$API_HOST"

# console
# -------
FROM base as console

# To add more packages:
#
# ```
# USER root
#
# RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
#     curl
#
#
# ```

COPY api api
COPY web web
COPY scripts scripts
````

The problem is, that I need a build time env var in web_build. Currently I can get around the problem by adding:

```
ENV MAP_GEOAPIFY_KEY=supersecret
ENV MAP_MAPTILER_KEY=supersecret
```

to the dockerfile. which is definitely not what I want. Since I don't want the keys to be visible in cleartext in the dockerfile.

I also tried to add them like this:

```
ARG MAP_GEOAPIFY_KEY
ENV MAP_GEOAPIFY_KEY=$MAP_GEOAPIFY_KEY
ARG MAP_MAPTILER_KEY
ENV MAP_MAPTILER_KEY=$MAP_MAPTILER_KEY
```

but without success - it seems to be undefined, at least it is not used when compiling.

What would be the preferred method to go here? Currently I just want to use this on my local machine. An integration to GitHub with gh actions etc. will come in a future step...

Thanks a lot for help,

Cheers!

Comment: It doesn't matter how you pass them, a key that gets saved into the image will be visible to anyone with access to the image. For security, you want to define these at container runtime as a secret, and if it's needed at build time, those build secrets should be discarded during the build and not saved into the image.